# convergence of unconstrained convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convergence

I encounter an optimization problem. The simplified version is like following:

Denote function $F(x):\mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$, where $F(x)$ is a smooth lower bounded convex function (i.e. $F(x)>0$). The hessian matrix of $F(x)$ is positive definite. However $F(x)$ is not a strongly convex function, namely we can not assume the hessian matrix $H(x)\succ m I_n$.

Suppose for the sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, the gradients of the $F(x)$ converge to zero:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|\mathbf{g}_k\|_2 = 0,\text{  and  }F(x_{k+1})\le F(x_{k}), k=0,1,...
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{g}_k=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} |_{x=x_k}$. Do we have the following result
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} F(x_{k}) = \inf _{x\in\mathbf{R}^n} F(x)?
\end{equation}

I expect $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} F(x_k) = \inf_{x\in\mathbf{R}^n} F(x)$. However, I can not find proofs for this result. There are some results about this problem. But unfortunately, either assume the optimum point of $F(x)$ is attainable, namely, there exists $x^*\in\mathbf{R}^n$, such that $F(x^*) = \inf F(x)$ or there exists $x^*\in\mathbf{R}^n$, such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k=x^*$.

Could any one help me to solve this problem or give me some comments? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your posting doesn't clearly state what it is that you're trying to prove and what you're willing to assume.  You also haven't told us how the sequence $\bf{x}_{k}$ is generated.  Could you clarify the question?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Hi, I have revised my question. Hopefully, it is more clear now. When I consider this problem, I encounter trouble that the sequence of $x_k$ may approach $\infty$, namely $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}
x_k=\infty$. For example for the function $F(x)=\exp(−x)$. For sure, for the function $F(x)=\exp(-x)$, the result in the question is correct. But for general smooth, lower bounded, convex function, do we also have the result correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about 
$$ F(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{\epsilon}{x^2}, \qquad \nabla F(x,y) = \Big( \frac{2x}{y}-\frac{2\epsilon}{x^3}, -\frac{x^2}{y^2} \Big), \qquad x,y>0$$
with the sequence $(x_k,y_k) = (k, k^2)$? Here $\epsilon$ is a small positive real number that makes the Hessian positive definite instead of semidefinite.

Then $F(x_k,y_k) = 1+\epsilon k^{-2}$ does not converge to the global infimum $\inf F(x,y) = 0$, but the sequence of gradients $$\mathbf{g}_k = \Big(\frac2k-\frac{2\epsilon}{k^3}, -\frac{1}{k^2}\Big)$$ converges to zero.

Informally speaking, the usual proof of convergence based on the inequality $f(y)\geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)$ would not apply here because while the gradients converge as $k^{-1}$ (not fast enough), the distance between $x_k$ and the closest minimum at $x=0$ diverges as $k$.

Comment: @ChristianClason Sorry, typo, that's meant to be $\epsilon/x^2$. Does it look correct to you now?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Without convergence (or at least boundedness) of the iterates, the result the OP is looking for won't hold.

Comment: @Kirill Thanks for constructing the counter example which clarifies my question!